# Google Map freezes when I try to open modal

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap, google-maps

I am trying to open a modal overlay on google maps. How it works: I click on the marker->click on the link in infoWindow (content)-> overlay modal has to open but map freezes and stops responding.

I tried show hidden element, bootstrap alerts but unfortunately nothing...
I am quite new in programming so the additional explanation will be appreciated.

```html
<div id="wrapper">
  <div id="over_map">
    <div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" arialabelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
      <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
          <div class="modal-header">
            <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Modal title</h5>
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria- label="Close">
    <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
    </button>
          </div>
          <div class="modal-body">
            ...
          </div>
          <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data- dismiss="modal">Close</button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div id="map"></div>
<script>
  function initMap() {
    var options = {
      zoom: 10,
      center: {
        lat: 59.4370,
        lng: 24.7536
      }
    }
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), options);
    //Array of markers
    var markers = [{
        coords: {
          lat: 59.3948,
          lng: 24.8118
        },
        iconImage: 'icon',
        content: '<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target = "#exampleModal"> Launch demo modal < /button>',
      },
      {
        coords: {
          lat: 59.4293,
          lng: 24.8352
        },
        content: '<h1>Lasna pubi</h1>'
      },
      {
        coords: {
          lat: 59.4079,
          lng: 24.6708
        }
      }
    ];
    //Loop through markers
    for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
      addMarker(markers[i]);
    }
    // Add Marker function
    function addMarker(props) {
      var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: props.coords,
        map: map,
        //icon:props.iconImage
      });
      //Check for custom icon
      if (props.iconImage) {
        // Set icon image
        marker.setIcon(props.iconImage);
      }
      //Check content
      if (props.content) {
        var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
          content: props.content
        });
        marker.addListener('click', function() {
          infoWindow.open(map, marker);
        });
      }
    }
  }
</script>
```

When the button is pressed in marker content window the modal with HTML elements opens

Comment: <style> #wrapper { position: relative; }
    #over_map { position: absolute; top: 500px; left: 880px;
     z-index: 99; }</style>

Comment: You are posting code in a snippet but the snippet can't be run. Why? Please provide a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) that demonstrates the issue.

Answer (score 0):

This issue is not due to your Google map freezing your modal. It's because you've added your Bootstrap's modal within other elements.

As stated in [Bootstrap's documentation](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/modal/):

> Modals use position: fixed, which can sometimes be a bit particular
>   about its rendering. Whenever possible, place your modal HTML in a
>   top-level position to avoid potential interference from other
>   elements. You’ll likely run into issues when nesting a .modal within
>   another fixed element.

Try placing your modal at the bottom of the body:

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="over_map"></div>
</div>
<div id="map"></div>

<div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" arialabelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Modal title</h5>
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
<span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
</button>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                ...
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

It was because I made one variable marker with multiple locations, not multiple separate locations, so code ran the first modal, but ignored second and showed only semitransparent layover.